# How to display list of string as key value json pair?

Tags: javascript

Below is my list of string :

```
var list = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"];
```

Now i want to display exact below output :

```
{
 "item1" : "",
 "item2" : "",
 "item3" : "",
 "item4" : "",
}
```

I tried with this :

```
var output = JSON.stringify(list, null, 4);
```

But getting like below :

```
[
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4"
]
```

```js
var list = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"];

var output = JSON.stringify(list, null, 4);

console.log(output);
```

But i want to turn my list of string in to key value json pair.So is there any simple way to turn my list of string in to 
key value pair without using loop??

Comment: Why "no loop"? Pretty much anything you do with an array typically involves a loop of one kind or another.

Comment: @deceze Actually i was thinking like may be any inbuilt method would be available like json.stringify which can do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can iterate over the array `list` and add each element to output as key and "" as value.

```js
var list = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"];

var output = {};
list.forEach(function(v){
   output[v] = "";
});
output = JSON.stringify(output);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can i have my output variable as string instead of object?

Comment: @Learning yes you can use `JSON.stringify()`, added in code.

Comment: But i want my each item to come on new line like my expected output

Comment: @Learning i don't understand the point of this, if you want to log it like an object why do you want to convert it to string?

Comment: Actually i have 1 textarea which is binded with 1 variable like this :<textarea ng-model="jsonText" > </textarea>.That is why i want this as a string rather than object.So at the end i would like to have the final output in jsonText which is string to display in textarea

Comment: you can add '\n' to your string to make it display like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149217/discussion-between-learning-and-dij).

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) .its used to create the object with in a function  .Then return object from the function

**ES6**

```js
var list = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"];

var output = list.reduce((a,b)=> (a[b]="" ,a),{})

console.log(output);
```

**ES5**

```js
var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];

var output = list.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[b] = ""
  return a
}, {})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `reduce` method which accepts a `callback` provided **function** which is applied on every item from your array.

```js
var list = ["item1","item2","item3","item4"];
var obj=list.reduce(function(obj,item){
  obj[item]="";
  return obj;
},{});
console.log(obj);
```